# Matlab input format

Tags: matlab, file-io, input, formatted-input

I have input files containing data in the following format.

```
65910/A
22 9 4 2 
9 10 4 1 
2 5 2 0 
4 1 1 0 
65910/T
14 7 0 4 
8 4 0 2 
1 2 0 0 
1 1 1 1
.
.
.
```

I need to take the input where the first line is a combination of `%d` and `%c` with a `/` in between and the next four line as a `4x4` integer matrix. I need to perform some work on the matrix and then identify them with the header information.

How can I take this input format in MATLAB?

Comment: Do you always have 4 lines of data in between lines of `#####/%c` ?

Comment: yes, It is always a 4x4 matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your file contains data that may be considered structured (or "formatted", if using MATLAB's terms), you can use the [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) function to read its contents. The main advantage of this function is that you don't need to specify how many times your "header+data" structure appears - the function just keeps going until it reaches the end of the file.

Given an input file with the following structure (let's call it `q35853578.txt`):

```
65910/A
22 9 4 2 
9 10 4 1 
2 5 2 0 
4 1 1 0 
65910/T
14 7 0 4 
8 4 0 2 
1 2 0 0 
1 1 1 1
```

We can write something like this:

```matlab
function [data,headers] = q35853578(filepath)
%// Default input
if nargin < 1
  filepath = 'q35853578.txt';
end
%// Define constants
N_ROWS = 4;
VALS_PER_ROW = 4;
NEWLINE = '\r\n';
%// Read structured file contents
fid = fopen(filepath);
headers = textscan(fid,['%u/%c' repmat([NEWLINE repmat('%u',1,VALS_PER_ROW)],1,N_ROWS)]);
fclose(fid);
%// Parse contents and prepare outputs
data = cell2mat(reshape(cellfun(@(x)reshape(x,1,1,[]),headers(3:end),...
  'UniformOutput',false),VALS_PER_ROW,N_ROWS).'); %'
headers = headers(1:2);
%// Output checking
if nargout < 2
  warning('Not all outputs assigned, some outputs will not be returned!')
end
%// Debug
clear ans fid N_ROWS NEWLINE VALS_PER_ROW filepath
keyboard; %// For debugging, delete/comment when done.
```

The resulting output is a 3d array of `uint32` (the output class can be changed by adjusting the inputs to `textscan`, as permitted by [`formatSpec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_formatSpec)):

```
ans(:,:,1) =

          22           9           4           2
           9          10           4           1
           2           5           2           0
           4           1           1           0


ans(:,:,2) =

          14           7           0           4
           8           4           0           2
           1           2           0           0
           1           1           1           1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's perfect!

Comment: @Md.AbidHasan - [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in stackoverflow. didn't know that @rayryeng